# DynamoDB throttling and hot partition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, throttling

I have a DynamoDB table that has provisioned read way above the consumed read, the utilization percentage is 70%.

I'm still getting throttling on the table and I couldn't figure out why. Once thing I'm suspecting is hot partition, but I'm unable to verify.

In the case of hot partitioning, does it throttle only the read to the hot partition, or to reads to all partitions?

Comment: Because of adaptive capacity, one partition receiving a lot of requests will take capacity from other partitions. You might also investigate DAX.

Answer (score 0):

A single partition can serve 1000WCU and 3000RCU. If you consume capacity on a single partition exceeding that you will be throttled.

If you have a number of keys sharing the same partition then throttling will be for all keys sharing that partition. DynamoDB does have Adaptive Capacity feature that can isolate hot keys but would sometimes have to have some throttling before that happens.

2 things you can try:

1. Enable CloudWatch contributor insights to understand which keys are throttling allowing you to make necessary changes.
2. Scale the table up to a large WCU manually, once complete re-enable your autoscaling as before, this will give you more partitions in the backend which may reduce your throttling by separating keys.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I tried the second method, setting the RCU to be more double the value of the current consumed read and the throttling still happened. 1 weird thing is that I wasn't able to get any throttling exception from our application.

Comment: Did you enable CCI?